# A expect script with multiple shell statements

Tags: python, shell, expect

I am using fabric, which is a deployment tool only working in Python2.*, to deploy my blog to the remote server.

However my blog is written with Python 3.5, so I am trying to use expect script and pyenv tool to automatically do the deployment thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10

spawn pyenv global system # changes python to 2.* version
spawn fab build  # gets files zipped

spawn fab deploy
expect "private key:"
send "x\r"
expect "Login password for 'myblog': "
send "*******\r"
expect eof

spawn pyenv global 3.5.1 # changes back
```

Then I found only `spawn pyenv global system` and `spawn fab deploy` part work.

Is this because the `spawn fab build` part doesn't need any input or feedback? But if so, it can't explain why the first statement `spawn pyenv global system` functioned. Also, weirdly, the last statement failed.

By the way, It's good when I run these four statements separately in commandline.

Comment: Have you checked out `autoexpect`? It records a shell session into an expect script and inspecting that might reveal what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: @Ben not yet, I don't know autoexpect before you say it. I'd try it now, tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried add `expect eof` after every single statement and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10

spawn pyenv global system
expect eof

spawn fab build 
expect eof

spawn fab deploy
expect "key:"
send "x\r"
expect "password"
send "*******\r"
expect eof

spawn pyenv global 3.5.1
expect eof
```

Maybe when you want to execute a command that needs no input like `ls -a`, you add the `expect eof` after it